# Strange issue with Wordpress sites, is it PHP Memory?

Tags: php

This has happened to me twice with the same host and I want to know the real cause.

I have multiple wordpress sites hosted on a shared server. One day when I attempt to visit any of the sites, the webpage simply downloads the index.php file. It happens on all wordpress sites but not on static sites hosted there.

I understand this is a php issue on the server, but what could be happening specifically? the only thing I could find when searching is something to do with memory limits. Is this common? Should I be worried about this host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a common issue on professional hosting and I think you've not to worry about it, at least if it doesn't come back again and again. Usually it is a configuration problem but, in this specific case, I assume it's temporary since the issue is occasional. It could be an Apache configuration update which was not perfect and so it generated the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess they have 2 strikes, hopefully it wont happen again.The main thing that bugs me is that unlike when a server is down, I can't set up any kind of alert to tell me when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could script a curl command and parse it to see if it is bringing down the php source or the html output.